# Difference between "condenar de" and "condenar por"

Tags: preposiciones

I have heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series (which takes place in Colombia):

> Ha sido juzgado y condenado del tráfico de cocaína en Colombia.

Is this identical in meaning to "Ha sido juzgado y condenado por (el) tráfico de cocaína" ? Are both equally usual?

My question comes from the fact that in Portuguese we'd only use the preposition "por" in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest at least in my country (Argentina) I think that we would use the expression you write **"juzgado y condenado por el ..."**. But my thoughts are that ***"...del..."*** in this case is trying to state the same meaning as ***"...por..."***, and that is = *because you did something, this is happening*. So maybe it has to do more with a nuance of different uses regarding the way of speaking of each country.

Comment: Plus, pronouns can be so squishy....  Thanks for the answer, and welcome to the site, Owen98.

Comment: @aparente001 what has this question to do with pronouns? May you meant "prepositions" instead?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - Yes, good catch, sorry.  They both start with PR.  Also, if you've been watching Meta.SE lately, you'll know that many of us have pronouns on the brain.

Answer (score 1):

In English, there is a slight difference in meaning between "convicted of" and "convicted for".  Consider the following two sentences,

```
He was convicted of speeding
```

and

```
He was convicted for speeding
```

In the first case, speeding identifies the law he broke.  In the second case, speeding specifies what act he committed.  This distinction may also be operating in Spanish.

Comment: Given that you break the law by committing an illegal action, I am unable to see the difference between both.

Comment: @alan - It's a subtle distinction, but I agree with Walter regarding the difference in English (which I know better than Spanish).